# What is the best way to format frontend AJAX calls for error handling?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, api

I'm using AngularJS with a PHP backend. Currently, my error handling is extremely messy, and if I wish to add in a new error, I must add it to every API call on my site (which would take a few hours).

I have an Angular service called `apiService` that I inject into each of my controllers. Here is an example of how I make a call to that service:

```
apiService.getUserData(userId).then(function(userData) {
  if(userData.status === 200) {
    doStuffWithUserData();
  } else {
    displayError();
  }
});
```

As you can see, it's quite messy since I have approximately 50 of these calls all with the same error handling. If I wish to add a new status to watch for, such as 403 forbidden, I would need to manually add this to each of my 50 calls.

This is a snippet from my `apiService`:

```
function runApiCall(apiRequest, apiData) {
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiRequest,
    data: apiData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  });
}


return {
  getUserData: function(userId) {
    var apiRequest = "http://mydomainhere.com/api/getUserData";
    var apiData = $.param({
      userId: userId
    });

    return runApiCall(apiRequest, apiData).then(function(data) {
      return data;
    });
  }
}
```

Since every single API call on my site goes directly through the `runApiCall` function, would it be possible to do all error handling there somehow?

Comment: can add a global error handler in an  `httpInterceptor`. Not hard to find exaamples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can augment your `runAPICall` function by **chaining** from the original promise returned by the `$http` service.

To **chain** a fulfilled promise properly, **return** the response to the chaining function. To **chain** a rejected promise properly, **throw** the error response to the chaining function.

```
function runApiCall(apiRequest, apiData) {
    var httpPromise = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiRequest,
        data: apiData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
     });

     var derivedPromise = httpPromise.then (
          function onFullfilled (response) {
              if (response.status === 200) {
                  doStuffWithUserData();
              } else {
                  displayOtherStatus();
              }
              //return response for chaining
              return response;
           },
           function onRejected (errorResponse) {
              if (errorResponse.status == 403) {
                  console.log("403 forbidden");
              } else {
                  console.log("other error " + errorResponse.status);
              };
              //throw errorResponse for chaining rejection
              throw errorResponse;
           }
      );

      return derivedPromise;
};
```

For the `$http` service, a response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the `onFulfilled` callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the `onRejected` callback will not be called for such responses.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)</sup>

A **rejected** promise can be **converted** to a fulfilled promise **by returning** to the `onRejected` function. Conversely, a **fulfilled** promise can be **converted** to a rejected promise **by throwing** to the `onFulfilled` function.

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[2](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

---

### Interceptors

The interceptors are service factories that are registered with the `$httpProvider` by adding them to the `$httpProvider.interceptors` array. The factory is called and injected with dependencies (if specified) and returns the interceptor.

For more information, see [AngularJS $http API Reference -- interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Comment: Works very well. And the explanation helps a heap. Thanks.

Comment: That makes me very happy to hear that.